# How can I always enable the tutorial popups for Batman's special combos?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

I always miss Batman's "special combos" enabled by keys like R,T,Y etc.

Is there a way to always display the tutorial messages?

Every time I play, I manually activate the tutorial with Ctrl-Right, but the next time I start the game it's off again.

Comment: I presume you mean you're activating them from the WayneTech page in your inventory? I hadn't tried turning them all on at once but it sounds like you've tried that. It may be that you can't have them all on at once as there would be multiple options at any given time, which would be constantly cluttering up your screen real estate.

Comment: Yes that from waynetech, but even if i enable tutorial for one of it next time it's disabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can enable them from the WayneTech page. And obviously, you can't enable two special combo tutorials, because they all happen when your combo reaches x8. Just enable your favorite combo tutorial.